# Hi, I am trying to print the name of an item of integer array, where item is a name given to math expression(sum etc)

Tags: java

System.out.println("Enter two numbers (aa,bb): ");

```
    int aa = sc.nextInt();
    int bb = sc.nextInt();
    int sum = aa + bb, sub = aa - bb, mult = aa * bb, div = aa / bb, mod = aa % bb;
    int[] operation = { sum, sub, mult, div, mod };
    
    for (int arr : operation) {
        System.out.println( arr+" of " + aa + " and " + bb + " is : " + arr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Items in the array have no name. Only indices. Which you don't have with a `for-each` loop. Option 1 (and my prefence) use a `Map` instead. Like,

```
Map<String, Integer> operMap = new HashMap<>();
operMap.put("sum", sum);
operMap.put("sub", sub);
operMap.put("mult", mult);
operMap.put("div", div);
operMap.put("mod", mod);

for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : operMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + " of " + aa 
            + " and " + bb + " is : " + e.getValue());
}
```

Option 2 use parallel arrays. Like,

```
String[] operName = { "sum", "sub", "mult", "div", "mod" };
int[] operation = { sum, sub, mult, div, mod };

for (int i = 0; i < operation.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(operName[i] + " of " + aa
            + " and " + bb + " is : " + operation[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked, i was trying to figure out any alternative of whether name of the array element( for eg. sum) can be printed without it giving its value ie. aa+bb.